# How to escape the & (ampersand) character in BibTeX?

Tags: symbols, bibtex, syntax

I would like to put a & character in a BibTeX publisher tag. Thus far I have tried:

```
\&
{&}
{\&}
"&"
```

with the full value enclosed in curly braces and double quotes. No matter what I do I always get a `Misplaced alignment tab character &.` error. Is there some special way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I had the same Problem. \& didnt work. I forgot to save the *my-bibtex-file*.bib after adding the backslash and before compiling everything (in my case 1. PDFLaTeX, 2. BibTex, 3. PDFLaTeX). Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem but $\&$ works for me

Comment: the worst here is using tabs to align content and not understanding that "tab" in that context is the table environment, not the "tab" char.

Comment: I've had "`Missing \endcsname inserted.`" issues using `\&` in my `*.bib`'s "`language`" field with `biber`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I have no problem with

```
publisher = {Harold \& Maude},
```

and running again `bibtex` and `pdflatex`

Comment: Not sure what my problem was...it seems to be working now though...

Comment: After making this change, remember to clear your auxiliary files so that the error doesn't persist!

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: There are no auxiliary files for the `bibtex` run.

Comment: @user2478 I didn't have either; I just cleared all construction files and it worked for me.

Comment: Just ran into this problem today, and while adding '\' to escape the & stops the error from appearing, it didn't print the character in the bibliography. Had to wrap it in curly brackets as well `publisher = { Foo {\&} Bar}`.

Comment: I have a Makefile do the build for me, which runs pdflatex, and bibtex, repeating as necessary. The trouble for me was that the & was unescaped, causing an error, and so running make again ran the pdflatex again, with error, then bailed. You have to run bibtex before rerunning pdflatex, or else delete the temporary files before doing so.

Answer (score 29):

When you've typed correctly in the `.bib` file but still receive errors, go check your `.bbl` file.

What I usually do is

1. Delete the whole erroneous line in the `.bbl` file, save, then close the file.
2. Make corrections or dummy (temporary) changes in the `.bib` file, then compile.

---

This is an example from my `.bbl` file:

```
\bibitem{Mohanty2005}

A.~K. Mohanty, M.~Misra, and L.~T.
Drzal.

\newblock {\em {Natural Fibers,
Biopolymers, and Biocomposites}}.

\newblock Taylor {\&} `&` Francis Group,
Florida, 2005.

\newblock ISBN-10: 0-8493-1741-X.
```

The `&` is the culprit, not `{\&}`.

What i do is delete the whole line (*newblock Taylor {\&} **&** Francis Group, Florida, 2005.*), save, then close the `.bbl` file. Make corrections or dummy changes in the `.bib` file, then compile.

---

You can simply delete the `&` in the `.bbl` file but the next time you make a change in the field that contains that `&` and compile your `.bib` file, the error will return.

Comment: Please use back-ticks `\`` to format inline code and 4-space indention for code blocks. Thanks.

Comment: This was the correct answer and also explanation for the compilation not working correctly in my case

Comment: thx, cleanup of all auxillary files helped in my case

Answer (score 18):

Clear your auxiliary files and then use the `\&` escape.

EDIT - and by auxiliary files, I mean that many GUI-based editors have a button or menu option for doing this. If you are doing it manually, delete the `.bbl` file (and perhaps the `.aux` file) and this should help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It would be nice to add that the files to remove are `.bbl` and possibly (but probably not necessarily) `.aux`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. After getting the same error message I typed a backslash in the `.bib` file:

```
publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
```

then I went to the `.bbl` file and modified the entry from:

```
\newblock John Wiley & Sons, 2nd edition.
```

to:

```
\newblock John Wiley \& Sons, 2nd edition.
```

and finally I recompiled, in my case: `latex->bibtex->latex->latex->dvipdfm->view pdf`. It worked :)

Comment: It is sufficient to change this in the `.bib` file and then recompile.  Your changes in the `.bbl` file will be overwritten by the `bibtex` run anyway.

Comment: For me the recompiled `latex->bibtex->latex->latex->dvipdfm->view pdf` sequence was essential! Without, after escaping the `&` with `\&` and saving, it was impossible to recompile my file.

Answer (score 2):

Typing backslash before the ampersand `\&` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue (using `biblatex`): escaping with `\&` and clearing the `.bbl` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

`\&`  works well.

I think you should clear all the log and output files including `.aux`, `.log`, `.bbl`, `synctex.gz` and `.pdf`, and then recompile the source files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a strange problem that the `{\&}`, which I thought was properly escaped, only caused an issue if it was used in the `author` field with biblatex.

For this field, remember to use two brackets (`{{…}}`) if you have a non-human name, such as an organization.
Because BibLaTex/BibTex otherwise change the author name according to their citation format, and apparently this could not handle

If you cite multiple authors and some of these are not in the expected format, you can still cite them by placing the entries into brackets like this e.g.:

```
author = {Aldo Example and Arushit Example and {@rugk} and {Company {\&} Value}},
```

The same error may happen with other signs like the at sign (`@`) that you usually can just write normally in LaTeX.