# Didn't use $, but still getting Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>

Tags: errors, syntax

So I'm trying to do a bibliography for my report on overleaf using LaTeX, and most of my sources are website that have URLs. 
I keep getting " Missing $ inserted. "
I have used any "$" signs, so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error.
Any help would be much appreciated thank you 
This is how I coded my sources

```
misc{website:Stanford,
  author = {Stanford Center for Professional Development},
  title = {CS221 - Artificial Intelligence Principles and Techniques},
  month = {October},
  year = {2016},
  URL ={http://scpd.stanford.edu/search/publicCourseSearchDetails.do?method=load&courseId=11747},
}

@misc{website:CIPS2,
  author = {CIPS},
  title = {Computer Science Accredited Programs},
  month = {October},
  year = {2016},
  URL ={http://www.cips.ca/ComputerScience},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I imagine you need to escape the `&` in the URL of `website:Stanford` this can be done by replacing `&` with `\&` ([How to escape the & (ampersand) character in BibTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7198/106162)).  You're also missing an `@`, it should be `@misc`.  If this isn't helpful we may need you to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: the `&` would give an error but not about `$` the most likely cause of that error is `_`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: The `.bib`entries you have shown look innocent enough (if processed with the right bibliography styles). Please consider constructing a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem for us. Ideally that would just be one block of code we can copy, paste and hit compile on that shows exactly the error you get. Do check if the errors are really the same, please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't "escape" the special characters (`$`, `_`, `$`, etc) if they occur in URL strings, as escaping them will almost certainly render the URL strings unusable.

Instead, encase the URL strings in `\url{...}` macros (and load the `url` package). Better still, use a bibliography style that knows how to handle fields named `URL` -- `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrvnat` are three such styles -- and load the `natbib` package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{website:Stanford,
  author = {Stanford Center for Professional Development},
  title = {CS221---{Artificial} Intelligence Principles and Techniques},
  month = {October},
  year = {2016},
  URL ={http://scpd.stanford.edu/search/publicCourseSearchDetails.do?method=load&courseId=11747},
}

@misc{website:CIPS2,
  author = {CIPS},
  title = {Computer Science Accredited Programs},
  month = {October},
  year = {2016},
  URL ={http://www.cips.ca/ComputerScience},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % for "\url" macro (used by natbib for "url" fields)
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\raggedright
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```