# What is the proper way to cite datasets in BibTex/LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

For an article I am writing in LaTeX, I need to cite two data sets. This is how I have written the entries in the bib.tex file:

```
@misc{qog2023,
  title={The Quality of Government Basic Dataset, version Jan23},
  author={Dahlberg, Stefan,  Aksel Sundström, Sören Holmberg, Bo Rothstein, Natalia Alvarado Pachon, Cem Mert Dalli & Yente Meijers.},
  year={2023},
  publisher={University of Gothenburg: The Quality of Government Institute}
}
@misc{epi2023,
  title={2022 Environmental Performance Index},
  author={Wolf, M. J., Emerson, J. W., Esty, D. C., de Sherbinin, A., Wendling, Z. A., et al. },
  year={2022},
  publisher={Yale Center for Environmental Law & Policy}
}
```

After compiling, the in-text citations appear as this:

[image]

enter image description here

This is how the LaTeX appears: (\cite{qog2023, epi2023})

No other citations appear to have this problem and I have been unable to troubleshoot. What is the correct way to cite this kind of data? Why won't the compiler generate the typical in-text citation format?

Comment: did you run `bibtex` or `biber`? (Not sure if you are using `bibtex` or `biblatex`, since your question didn't really specify and you tagged `biblatex`.)

Comment: Biber, I think: \usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

Comment: Please can you post a complete compilable document? Otherwise, we're first tasked with reverse-engineering from your output. You should be using `and` in fields which are lists such as `author` and you have unescaped ampersands. Look at `biber`'s output. Does it complain about these entries? I'm guessing once you correct them, the problem will disappear.

Comment: The immediate error that will stop compilation here are the commas in the name fields: Regardless of the desired output all names must be separated with `and`. Commas must not be used to separate several names (they are only used to separate family and given name). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864.

Comment: But then the unescaped `&` is also going to be a problem (it will cause a different kind of error, though): You need to write `\&` instead in the `publisher` field. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7198/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/35864)

Comment: None of these two issues are specific to data sets. If you use `biblatex` (at least if your version is sufficiently new) you can use the entry type `@dataset` instead of `@misc` for data sets (though the output will be largely identical to the output you'd get from `@misc`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Trading commas for and solved the issue. I am unable to post the entire document for privacy concerns of the research.